# Change the scale from number to percentage - Gauge Chart

Tags: javascript, spotfire

I am creating Gauge chart from the below java script. I am almost there, just want to convert the scales to percentages. Link to java script - http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2016/03/custom-gauge-from-calc-value-70.html

And the JS is below:--

```
custom gauge from calc value (7.0+)
html:
calculated value:
<span id=calcValue><SpotfireControl id="y0ursp07f1r3c41cV41u3" />
</span>

<HR>

<DIV style="WIDTH: 400px; HEIGHT: 320px" id=gauge></DIV>


js
 resource=[
 "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js",
 "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/justgage/1.0.1/justgage.min.js"
]

//add scripts to head
$.getScript(resource[0],function(){
 $.getScript(resource[1],init)
})

init = function(){
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge", 
    value: "22", 
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Visitors"
  });  

  //refresh gauge when calcvalue changes
  $(calcValue).on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    g.refresh($(this).text())
  })

}
```

---

Really appreciate your time and help!!

Best,
Keyur Parekh